# jQuery - Show one DIV and hide multiple others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on page load event, one DIV will be `display:block` and two others are set to `display:none`.

Once the user clicks a button to view one of the hidden DIV's the style will switch so the hidden DIV will then be set to `display:block` and the other will be `display: none`.

I have this working currently, but I was looking to see if there was a more efficient way of approaching this.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9bnq8dp/1/):

[New fiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/p9bnq8dp/1/):

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Providing a link to code isn't sufficient on SO: as links can dies, we usually request that you also post the code. And also, to me, it isn't quite clear what the problem is, you should clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add Common Class to all the tab headers
2. Add `data-target` attribute to show the element when clicked on tab-header
3. Group all the tab-contents inside on container

See the changes highlighted in `HTML` and inline comments in `Javascript`.

Html:

```
<div class="pageTabs">
    <div class="tabs">
        <span id="overview-btn" class="active tabHeader" data-target="#overview-section">Overview</span>
        //                                    ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        <span id="itinerary-btn" class="tabHeader" data-target="#itinerary-section">Full Itinerary</span>
        //                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        <span id="map-btn" class="tabHeader" data-target="#map-section">Map</span>
        //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="overview" id="overview-section">
        <p>Intro 1</p>
        <p>Intro 2</p>
        <p>Intro 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="itinerary" id="itinerary-section">
        <div class="heading">Day 1</div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <hr>
        <div class="heading">Day 2</div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <hr>
        <div class="heading">Day 3</div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <hr>
        <div class="heading">Day 4</div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <hr>
        <div class="heading">Day 5</div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="map" id="map-section">map here...</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // When tab-header is clicked
    $('.tabHeader').on('click', function () {

        // Add active class to the clicked element, and remove from other tab-headings
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        // Get the target element show it and hide other tab-contents
        $($(this).data('target')).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/p9bnq8dp/2/

Answer (score 0):

Put all your css changes in classes in a css file and use `.addClass('yourclass')` in your Jquery script (don't forget to load the css file).

for .css("display", "none") use Jquery `.hide()` with/without `.toggle()`

Answer (score 0):

Added class tab to all the individual tabs.

Note:Changed them from span to button since they are clickable elements and would get keyboard focus this way.

Also added a data attribute which contains the id of the corresponding content section.

Added a class content-section to each content section.

```
<div class="pageTabs">
    <div class="tabs">
        <button id="overview-btn" class="active tab" data-content="overview-section">Overview</button>
        <button id="itinerary-btn" class="tab" data-content="itinerary-section">Full Itinerary</button>
        <button id="map-btn" class="tab" data-content="map-section">Map</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="overview content-section selected" id="overview-section">
        <p>Intro 1</p>
        <p>Intro 2</p>
        <p>Intro 3</p>

    </div>


    <div class="itinerary content-section" id="itinerary-section">

        <div class="heading">Day 1</div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <hr />

        <div class="heading">Day 2</div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <hr />

        <div class="heading">Day 3</div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <hr />

        <div class="heading">Day 4</div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <hr />

        <div class="heading">Day 5</div>
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <hr />

     </div>

     <div class="map content-section" id="map-section">

        map here...

     </div>
</div>
```

Added the following jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab').on('click',function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var selectedContentId = '#' + $this.data('content');
        $('.tab').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
        $('.content-section').removeClass('selected');
        $(selectedContentId).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p9bnq8dp/8/

Answer (score 0):

You should the following inorder to optimize your code.

1. Should rename the "**overview-btn**" to "**overview**"
2. Should rename the "**itinerary-btn**" to "**itinerary**"
3. Should rename the "**map-btn**" to "**map**"

Then use the following code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                 
      jQuery('.tabs span').click(function(){
        //First remove the class 'active' from the .tabs of all spans
        jQuery('.tabs span').removeClass('active');
        // We will make only the clicked one active (color pink)
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        //hide all the .overview class 
        jQuery('.overview').hide();
        //then only the clicked tabs "id"-section 
        jQuery('#'+jQuery(this).attr('id')+"-section").show();
        
      });
      //initial setting
      jQuery('.overview').hide();
      jQuery('#overview-section').show();
    });
```

```css
.pageTabs .tabs span {background-color: #797979; color: #fff!important; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; line-height: 30px; margin: 0!important; padding: 0 12px; text-decoration: none;}
    .active {background-color: #e10981!important;}
    .content {margin: 10px 0 0 0;}
    .overview {display: block;}
    .overview .itineraryTable {width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 100%; background-color: #58595b; color: #58595b;}
    .overview .itineraryTable .titleRow {background-color: #e10981!important; border: 1px solid #e10981!important; color: #fff; font-size: 14px; padding: 4px; text-align: left;}
    .overview .itineraryTable th {color: inherit; background-color: #fff; width: 15%; border: 1px solid #bcbec0; text-align: left; padding: 4px;}
    .overview .itineraryTable td {border: 1px solid #bcbec0; background-color: #fff; color: #797979; padding: 4px; width: 95%;}
    .itinerary {display: none;}
    .itinerary .heading {color: #e10981!important; font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px;}
    .itinerary p {color: #797979; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; margin: 10px 0; text-align: justify;}
    .itinerary hr {background-color: #bcbec0; border: medium none; height: 1px; margin: 15px 0;}
    .map {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pageTabs">
                            <div class="tabs">
                                <span id="overview" class="active">Overview</span>
                                <span id="itinerary">Full Itinerary</span>
                                <span id="map">Map</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="overview" id="overview-section" style="display:block;">
                                <p>Intro 1</p>
                                <p>Intro 2</p>
                                <p>Intro 3</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="overview" id="itinerary-section">

                            <div class="heading">Day 1</div>
                            <p>blah blah blah</p>
                            <hr>

                            <div class="heading">Day 2</div>
                            <p>blah blah blah</p>
                            <hr>

                            <div class="heading">Day 3</div>
                            <p>blah blah blah</p>
                            <hr>

                            <div class="heading">Day 4</div>
                            <p>blah blah blah</p>
                            <hr>

                            <div class="heading">Day 5</div>
                            <p>blah blah blah</p>
                            <hr>

                        </div>

                        <div class="overview" id="map-section">

                            map here...

                        </div>
```

Please let me know , if this solves your problem